# Как повернуть Header в TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте.

Есть `TreeView`. Как можно повернуть текст `Header'a`?

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header="Test1">
</TreeViewItem>
```

То есть так, чтобы числа развернулись, а кнопка `expand` осталась в том же положении

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Положите, например Label в Header и его поверните...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>

                <Label Content="123" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Label.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-89.691"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Label.RenderTransform>

                </Label>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <TreeViewItem/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

</Window>